# Installing CURL on Ubuntu Karmic

Tags: ubuntu, curl

Trying to get this up and running:

https://github.com/cloudnull/massupload

I have everything except CURL installed and when I attempt to, it fails with the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  curl
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 196kB of archives.
After this operation, 311kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  curl
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/main curl 7.19.5-1ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/curl_7.19.5-1ubuntu2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
```

Thank you!

Comment: It is past time to upgrade.  You should start looking at that now.  Yuor system is almost certainly vulnerable to several security issues.  Support was dropped for that release over 18 months ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Karmic is no longer supported, you have get update from old-versions mirror.

add:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic main restricted
```

to sources.list

Comment: I am sure you meant karmic, not gutsy right?

Comment: Thanks! That worked... after I changed 'gutsy' to 'karmic. Very much appreciated!